# If $N \triangleleft G$ and $\gcd(|N|,[G:N]) = 1$, then $N$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I want to show that under the given the conditions, that $f(N) = N$ for any $f \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$.  I know that $f(N)$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that $|f(N)| = |N|$, but I'm not sure how to use the fact that the order of $|N|$ and the index of $N$ in $G$ are coprime to show that, say, $f(N) \subseteq N$ (if that's even what I should be doing).  Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Hint: consider Sylow subgroups.

Comment: @SteveD I know that if $P \triangleleft G$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, then it is a characteristic subgroup of $G$.  But I'm not seeing how exactly this relates.

Comment: If $N$ contains a Sylow subgroup, it contains them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that $\exists$ $H  \le G$ and $|H| = |N|$

Then $HN \le G$, and $|G:HN|\times|HN:N| = |G:N|$

Therefore $\gcd(|HN:N|, |N|) = 1$

$|HN:N| = \frac{|H| \times |N|}{|H \cap N| \times |N|} = \frac{|H|}{|H \cap N|}$

$\gcd(\frac{|H|}{|H \cap N|}, |N|) = 1$ and $|H| = |N|$

$|H \cap N| = |H| \Rightarrow H = N$

So, $N$ is the unique subgroup of a given order, hence it is characteristic, since $|f(N)| = |N|$, $\forall f \in Aut(G)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @fedor. Why does it follow that $\gcd([HN:N],|N|)=1$?

Comment: @Möbius Dickus Let $|G:N| = |G:HN|\times|HN:N| = mn$. 

So $\gcd(mn, |N|) = 1$. If $\gcd(n, |N|) = d >1$, then $mn$ and $|N|$ would have a common divisor $d$ as well, so $\gcd(|G:N|, |N|) > 1$ as well.